# I am admin on my machine, I am the only user but I cannot delete a folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I am administrator on my machine. I am the only registered user, but I cannot delete a folder.
I tried running explorer.exe as administrator, but I still get the same error message, that I require permissions to delete the folder.

How can I remove this need? Is there a different file explorer that can do this for me?

Comment: What folder are you trying to delete? What is the exact error message? There can be a few reasons why its not working. Currently there's too many details missing to come go a conclusion.

Comment: @LPChip the accepted answer covered my question. The error message was that I require permissions to delete the folder even though I was admin. Thank you

Comment: I was referring to the exact error. I read already that your error was something like that, but the exact error can be googled for too and some errors may look very much alike but mean something different.

Comment: no, the exact error was "You require permissions to delete this folder" which is what I said

Comment: No, you didn't say that. You said "that I require permissions to delete this folder" which is not a Windows error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open Command Prompt as Administrator. Confirm to the UAC Admin Approval dialog if required. Then run `takeown /f "Full path of the folder"`. Then run `icacls "Full path of the folder" /grant Administrators:F`. Now you will have full ownership on the folder. Now you can delete it.

Comment: it would be nice if you explained each command's point as well

Comment: @JohnDemetriou `takeown` changes ownership on filesystem objects and `icacls` changes the ACL permissions on objects. Here as you are member of the Administrators local group then it gives you F (Full Access) to the file/folder.

Comment: Add it in the answer. It's better

Answer (score 0):

Try obtaining ownership over the file/directory you're trying to delete. Then go to Properties > Security > Advanced and enable inheritance (if disabled). Apply changes and try to delete it again.

Comment: How does one take ownership? You could improve this answer by including more details and screenshots of the process you are describing.

Comment: @JimDiroffII properties > security > advanced > owner (click change)