# Cannot delete a file on Windows 10. I am the administrator. Tried to follow many tutorials, but anything work

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, file-permissions

I installed a game into my computer. Tried to uninstall but it didnt worked. So I started manually deleting its files. I have deleted all but one file, that does not allow me to delete it.

[image]

This is the file:

[image]

I tried to follow many tutorials, but none worked.

On files properties -> securities -> advanced, it says that is unable to display current owner:

[image]

When I click on change, it says that I do not have permission to view the object permissions.

[image]

When I click on share, it says that the administrator and everyone have full access, but still I cannot delete it.

[image]

I also tried some command prompt changes to be able to delete the file. Like:

1. "net user administrator /active:yes", for which I receive the following message: "The command completed successfully".
2. I also tried to follow the instructions of this other response in super user: [I am admin on my machine, I am the only user but I cannot delete a folder](https://superuser.com/questions/1580441/i-am-admin-on-my-machine-i-am-the-only-user-but-i-cannot-delete-a-folder)

But I got the answer form command prompt: "ERROR: Access is denied".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When everything you try fails to delete the file, you need a good unlocker app.

For Windows 11 and also then for Windows 10, you can use IOBit unlocker.

https://www.iobit.com/en/iobit-unlocker.php

I have this here, it works well and is safe.

You may need to restart the computer after IO bit has unlocked the file. Also make sure you start IO bit as Administrator

[image: IO Bit Unlocker]

Comment: Thanks! I installed and used it. It says the file is unlocked, but I still cannot delete it.

Comment: If the file has been unlocked, restart the computer and then delete it.  I added that to my answer.  Do not forget to start IO Bit as Administrator.,

Comment: Thanks, it worked now!

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into safe mode and deleting it.  If that doesn't work, boot to recovery and select Troubleshooting -> Command Prompt and delete from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script on your powershell console

1. Search for powershell on your pc (it's reinstalled / an administrative tool)
2. RUN POWERSHELL as administrator
3. TYPE C IN YOUR KEYBOARD TO SWITCH DRIVE TO DRIVE C:
4. TYPE THE BELOW....

Remove-Item - Path C:\Users\Juizz\Games\HyperPlay\theunfettered -Force

If it dosnt

type 'Mscofig' without the punctuation marks

A window will open, check for **boot** options

The tab displays some list of booting options, choose only **boot to safe mode**

Repeat the FIRST SOLUTION

This should WORK FINE

Let me know if there are still Any issues